# How to add row double click event listener when extending grid panel with Ext.define()?

Tags: javascript, extjs, gridpanel, extjs4

I am extending GridPanel with Ext.define() (Ext v4).

I need to get the row data when a grid row is double clicked. At this point I cannot even get the event listener working:

```
Ext.define('Application.usersGrid', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.GridPanel',
alias: 'widget.usersgrid',


viewConfig: {
    listeners: {
        dblclick: function(dataview, index, item, e) {
            alert('dblclick');
        }
    }
},
...
```

What is wrong here?

If anyone needs the answer- this is the right way:

```
Ext.define('Application.usersGrid', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.usersgrid',


viewConfig: {
    listeners: {
        itemdblclick: function(dataview, record, item, index, e) {
            alert('itemdblclick');
        }
    }
},
...
```

http://dev.sencha.com/new/ext-js/4-0/api/Ext.grid.GridView#event-itemdblclick

Comment: Is it listeners should part of GridPanel or SelectonModel, you hide it in viewConfig

Comment: I'm following this post: http://hutten.org/bill/extjs/2011/03/extjs-4-pr3---how-to-get-doubl.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't need to put the listener in the viewconfig. Here is my working configuration:

```
listeners : {
    itemdblclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
        alert('working');
    }
},
```

Another thing is, you seems to have used `Ext.grid.GridPanel` in the extend property. But in documentation it's `Ext.grid.Panel`. But even with gridpanel, everything seems to work fine.

I would suggest to use the Ext JS 4 terms as it might cause to application breakage later in other 4.x versions.

Now, if you are using the new MVC architecture, you will want to move these actions to the controller rather than the view. You can refer to the MVC Architecture guide for details.

Comment: Thank you for the tips - it works this way for me as well. Changed my code to exctend grid.Panel. I was following the example at http://hutten.org/bill/extjs/2011/03/extjs-4-pr3---how-to-get-doubl.html and it was using viewConfig.. perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: @Petrunov, you are not missing something.. i think the writer of hutten.org is doing a mistake "In ExtJS 4.0 you NEED to listen for events on the GridPanel’s view, VIA the “viewConfig”"... this is wrong..

Comment: Btw, I tried adding the listeners directly to the panel on my own but it didn't worked - perhaps becase I was trying with events like 'dblclick' and 'rowdblclick' - couldn't find 'itemdblclick' on my own :/

Comment: @Edo.. I think you are in some misunderstanding. Where did you read "In ExtJS 4.0 you NEED to listen for events on the GridPanel’s view, VIA the viewConfig"? Have a look at the events of View and Panel in docs.

Comment: @Petrunov, yup.. that could be a reason it didn't work for you. try your code with itemdbclick in viewconfig and let us know the result...

Comment: Ok Abdel, I was just trying your example and on itemdblclick I did alert(record) - it was undefined.

Then I moved the listeners back to viewConfig as you suggested in the latest comment, but this time with the right 'itemdblclick' event - now record is an object.

Answer (score 2):

With the MVC approach in ExtJS 4 there's another smart way too to define such handlers. Some example code:

```
Ext.define('App.controller.Documents', {

  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
  stores: ['Documents'],
  models: ['Document'],
  views: [
    'document.List',
    'document.Edit',
    'document.Preview'
  ],  

  init: function() {

    this.control({

      /*  
       * a cool way to select stuff in ExtJS 4
       */
      'documentlist': {
        itemdblclick: this.editDocument
      },  

      /*  
       * simple access to components
       */
      'documentedit button[action=save]': {
        click: this.updateDocument
      },  

    }); 

  },  

  editDocument: function(grid, record) {
    var view = Ext.widget('documentedit');
    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
  },  

  updateDocument: function(button) {
    var win = button.up('window'),  // new selection API
        form   = win.down('form'),  // in ExtJS 4
        record = form.getRecord(),
        values = form.getValues();

    record.set(values);
    win.close();
  }
});
```

Comment: With this approach, howto you handle override listener ? I mean, how about if you get some problem like on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730552/howto-override-listener-in-gridpanel-on-extjs4) thread ?

Answer (score 0):

```
listeners: {
        select: 'xxxx',

        itemdblclick: function (dv, record, item, index, e) {
            var myBtn = Ext.getCmp('btnEdit');
            myBtn.onClick();
        }
    },
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, posting a code as an answer might not be very useful without explanation. Could you edit your answer to had some explanation? You might be interested to read [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).